# Is it possible to score a KPI based on todays date?

Tags: date, sharepoint-2010, formulas, performancepoint, kpi

I am building a KPI in PerformancePoint - SharePoint 2010 and have the following setup:

We have some files that are stored and they have a "Review/Expiry Date" field. Is it possible to get the KPI to display red if the review date is less than todays date?

I thought this might be something simple but it's turning out to be really hard to find a solution that I can use in PerformancePoint.

I can build the functionality into XML but that would then seperate these files from all the other KPI's I have!

Thanks a million in advance for any assistance.

Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is heavily dependent on the type of data source you're using.  If you have your data in a SQL Server table, it should be trivial to add another column that generates a "days left to complete" or something, and you can set your target thresholds accordingly.

So I would create a table that looks like this:

```
Item   | Review Date | Days Remaining
Task 1 | 10/01/2011  | 95
Task 2 | 1/1/2011    | -30
Task 3 | 2/28/2011   | 12
```

The Days Remaining column would just be something like

```
SELECT DATEDIFF("dd", [Review Date], GETDATE())
```

If you want to do this in a SharePoint list, you can also accomplish this easily.  I created a simple task list and added a Calculated Column called Remaining Days.  I used the following formula:

```
=[Due Date]-[Today]
```

When you create your KPI, just create a Target for Days Remaining.  You want Larger is Better, Green is anything above 5 days, Yellow between 1 and 5, and Red is anything less than 1.

The ease of this really depends on your data source.  Good luck.

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks for your response!

The data is stored in a document library within SharePoint. I have managed to resolve this myself but having just seen your solution it is excatly what I did to resolve it so a very good and informative response. Thanks for spending the time to respond. Rich